# Quarto document renders properly but does not deploy in GitHub pages

Tags: r, github-actions, github-pages, quarto

I am trying to deploy a Quarto html document to GitHub pages. It is rendering properly and has generated a gh-pages branch in the [repository](https://github.com/OSM-Catalan/portals_bcn/). However, the [webpage](https://osm-catalan.github.io/portals_bcn/) contains only the repo readme.

I designed a Quarto document, which renders properly. You can find a version [here](https://rpubs.com/tururut/1138572). I ran `quarto publish gh-pages`, which properly created a [gh-pages branch](https://github.com/OSM-Catalan/portals_bcn/tree/gh-pages). The html code looks right and the figures look like they should. However, it did not deploy. I further pushed a commit and it ran [this github action](https://github.com/OSM-Catalan/portals_bcn/blob/main/.github/workflows/quarto-publish.yml), [which was successful](https://github.com/OSM-Catalan/portals_bcn/actions/runs/7611292077). However, after over an hour, it has not deployed. At this moment, I am at a loss and do not understand what (or if) I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Error was due to the fact that it needed to use data from the gh-pages branch.